# How can I compute this limit?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I have to compute

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(-n)\left(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{n^n}{n!} \right)$$

I think the value is 1, but i don't know how to proof this. Do I have to estimate the remainder of the Taylor expansion of the exponential function? Does anyone have a hint for me?

So do I have to show that $$ R_{n} (x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{\exp(t)}{n!} \left(x-t\right)^{n}\mathrm{d}t $$ goes to 0? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you think Riemann sum will help somehow?

Comment: Numerics strongly suggest the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, but I have no proof yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you express this in terms of the series-residual
$$ f(n)= \exp(-n)\cdot (\exp(n) - (n^{n+1}/(n+1)! + n^{n+2}/(n+2)! + ... ) $$
you can write
$$ f(n) = 1 - {(n^{n+1}/(n+1)! + n^{n+2}/(n+2)! + ... ) \over \exp(n)} $$
and this can furtherly be reduced to
$$ f(n) = 1 - {n^n\over n!} \cdot {(n/(n+1) + n^2/(n+1)/(n+2) + ... ) \over \exp(n)} $$
and then to
$$ f(n) = 1 - {(n/e)^n\over n!} \cdot \left( {1 \over 1+1/n} + {1 \over (1+1/n)(1+2/n)} + ...  \right) $$
Call that infinite sum in the parenthese as $R(n)$, then it seems as if a not bad accurate estimate is $ R(n) \approx 1.174 n^{0.506}$ (taken by some values by nonlinear trendline using Excel, so the values might be improvable). Then - I think- the Stirling-formula for the estimate of the factorial should come into play...

As it was already conjectured in the comments, it seems that the final result goes to 1/2 by simple numerical tests using the series representations of $R(n)$.

Comment: $R(n)$ is probably going to be $\sqrt{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$ (plus some error terms).